# Script that converts all instances of a specific filtered selection of HREF values to another value

Tags: javascript, html, href, greasemonkey

Since Firefox cannot open links in a new tab if they have a HREF tag divert to a function, perhaps a script could be used to to convert them; i.e.  to the actual HREF.

I can see what foo does;

```
function foo(x) { self.location.href = 'page.asp?ID=' + x }
```

So I need to change all instances of;

`<a href="javascript:foo(12354)">`

to;

```
<a href="page.asp?ID=12354">
```

where 12354 is the variable and the only HREF tags that need to be modified are the ones that call out to the function foo ?

something like;

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++)
{
    if(anchors[i].href includes 'foo' then
    {
      val1 = get the value within the parenthesis; i.e. 12354
      anchors[i].href = "page.asp?ID=" + val1 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the links that have `foo` text in `href` attribute, extract the id and assign a new value:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="javascript:foo"]'), function(a) {
    var id = a.href.match(/\d+/)[0];
    a.setAttribute('href', 'page.asp?ID=' + id);
});
```